# Nock, Async/Await, Bitbucket: Intercept does not return before Chai begins assertion

Tags: node.js, async-await, bitbucket, chai, nock

I have an endpoint that makes an external API call.

```
//outside.js
const createTicket = async () => {
    try{
    const someOptions =  { /*stuff here*/}
        results = await rp.post('https://xcxxx.zendesk.api.com/request.json', someOptions)
        return results; 
    }catch(e) {
        return e
    }
}


//router.js
const {createTicket} = required("../outside.js")
router.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    /*do stuff*/
    createTicket();

    return res.status(200).send();
})

//index.js
app.use(require("router.js"));
...


//index.test.js
const server=require("../index.js");  /*test calls index.js, which uses router.js*/
const nock = require("nock");
const chai = require("chai");
/*lots of other requires*/

describe("Should send ticket when POST fails", function(done){
   let ticketNock= nock(`https://xcxxx.zendesk.com`)
                .log(console.log)
                .post('/api/v2/requests.json')
                .reply(200);
    chai.request(server)
                .post("/test")
                .send({info: 'fail this'})
                .then((res) => {

                    expect(ticketNock.isDone()).to.equal(true);


                    nock.restore();
                    nock.cleanAll();
                    done();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    done(error);
                })
```

When I am testing `/test`, I am trying to use Nock to intercept the `https://external.api.com/request.json`. The test passes fine locally, but when I push it to bitbucket and runs the pipeline, it fails to intercept.

My guess is that the code in `router.js` does not call await.

My question is, is there any work around **without changing the source code**?
Spying and stubbing may not be a choice either.

Otherwise, if anyone has insights on why this only fails Bitbucket, I'd love to hear from you as well. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, the expectation of your controller for `POST /test` is that it responds before it knows if the call to the external API was successful? Your guess seems accurate, your test is probably asserting before the request to external is actually made. It is still possible to test this, however, we'd need more info about your tests before we could provide feedback.

Comment: My assumption is that Bitbucket itself isn't a factor, but more the latency compared to other things you've tried. Plus things like redirects could add up in how long it takes the request to resolve.

Comment: @MattR.Wilson, thank you for thecomment. I have updated the code above. Please let me know your thoughts.